# how to determine a transformation matrix for transforming x and y with specific equation?

Tags: matrices

I need to determine a matrix that can be used to:

a)  transform $x$ and $y$ using equations

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x'=3x + 4y \\ 
y'=-x + 2y \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Then I need to:

b) Transform a triangle $(0,0),(1,0),(1,1)$ using this transformation

c) What are the coordinates of point $(10,10)$ in the basis of transformation?

Could I have some advise? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any advise guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x'=3x + 4y \\ 
y'=-x + 2y \\ 
\end{array}
\right. \Rightarrow \left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x'=(3,4)(x,y)\\ 
y'=(-1,2)(x,y) \\ 
\end{array}
\right.$

$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x'=(3,4)(x,y)\\ 
y'=(-1,2)(x,y) \\ 
\end{array}
\right. \Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}  3 & 4 \\ -1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} x` \\ y` \end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix}  3 & 4 \\ -1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix}  3 & 4 \\ -1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix}  3 & 4 \\ -1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 7 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$

as itcan be seen, image of triangle is also a triangle (because kernel of matrix is $\{0\}$)

Comment: That seems to answer A, but what about B and C?

Comment: i have to add that i could not fully understand the demand of option C.I guess i can help you if you provide more information

Comment: Oh thank you, this helps. The C option was about change of basis, $(10,10)$ is the new basis.